# How does the B737's 'throttle offline' setting work?

Tags: boeing-737, autothrust, rejected-takeoff

I'm concerned about [this article](http://www.flaps2approach.com/journal/2014/8/4/boeing-737-800-takeoff-procedure-simplified.html):

> Throttle online means that the crew can override the autothrottle logic, while Throttle offline means that the logic cannot be overridden.

So for example - rejected take-off:
Table shows that at 60 knots 'throttle mode is offline' and we cannot override.

So at 60 knots we can't first move throttle to idle (because it's blocked?) before turning off A/T? Or we can same as at 80 knots?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That article is about somebody's simulation. In the real aircraft, the pilots can always override the A/T and can always turn it off entirely. The A/T will push the throttles toward the target position, but not so hard you can't move them easily yourself. (You may need to turn them off to get them to stop trying to push the power up, but for an action like pulling them to idle for an aborted takeoff before THR HOLD engages at 84 knots, the pilot can easily override them.)

Also, the terms "online" or "offline" aren't used with reference to the authrottles in any Boeing documentation that I've seen.  They may be off, or they can be on -- in which case the mode may be "armed" or any of various other modes. But not on/off line.

Mostly the info in that article is okay, but the table referenced seems to reflect some misunderstanding about what the pilots can/can't do with the thrust levers... at least, with regard to the actual aircraft. That info may be spot-on with regard to the simulation the author is writing about.